# PHP - How to merge Array when numbers of arrays not know because getting arrays through loop

Tags: php, mysql

Struggling with `array_merge` function.
It works fine when we use it like this.

```
    array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

In my case both arrays are from MySQL result.
See the following code for understanding it better.

```
    $getfilelist = 'select * from  fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
    $FILE = $db->query($getfilelist);
     $file_tot = count($FILE);
    for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
    { 
   $artist = explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist']); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,C,D` in second.

    }  
    print_r($artist);
```

This prints something like this.

```
    Array // artist in first row
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => B
             )

    Array // artist in second row
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => C
              array[2] => D
             )
```

I want array should -

```
    Array 
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => B
              array[2] => C
              array[3] => D
             )
```

I tried following code.

```
    $getfilelist = 'select * from  fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
    $FILE = $db->query($getfilelist);
     $file_tot = count($FILE);
    for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
    { 
   $artist = explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist']); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,B,C` in second.

    $merged = array_merge($artist); 
    $unique = array_unique($merged);
    }  
    print_r($unique);
```

Results is

```
     Array 
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => B
             )

    Array 
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => C
              array[2] => D
            )
```

This is not expected result.
In above code, I need something like this -> `array_merge($FILE[0], $FILE[1]);` for get expected result. Can't figure out how to code it.

I know `array_merge` function require two or more array but can't figure out how give both array to `array_merge` function.
Suggest me how to print only `A,B,C,D` in above case. Is I'm missing something? Or this is bad coded script?

Comment: So you want to have all unique entries from the 'sum' of the two database rows? E.g. when `$a = [A, B, C, D]` and `$b = [A, B, E]` you want to get an output like `$out = [A, B, C, D, E]`?

Comment: there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: if this is what was asked i suggest to use the `DISTINCT` operator in MySQL instead.

Comment: You not understood my case. `array_merge(array1, array2);` here `array1, array2` are  not known in my case. That's the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DISTICT` Keyword in your `SELECT` query. If you use `DISTINCT` MySQL will only give you unique values:

```
$getfilelist = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fileartist fid IN (210,209)'
```

Comment: Okay, I'm trying it. Please be with me here . :)

Comment: Artist names are saved as string like this-> in first row `You,Me,Someone`  in second row `You,Me` SQL giving both because both are not equal.

Comment: you could then combine the select statement for the rows you want to have with a select statement which will give you all the data. In the `FROM` part you could insert only the values from the table wich are relevant (should be unique), e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT firstName, lastName FROM fileartist fid) IN (210, 209)`

Comment: Hoq to apply `DISTINCT` here -> `$getfilelist = 'select DISTINCT * from file , fileartist where file.cid = '.$parentid.' AND fileartist.fid = file.id order by kram desc';`

Answer (score 0):

you code is right , your issue that you are printing you output inside the loop

```
for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
{
    // .....
    $merged = array_merge($artist);
    $unique = array_unique($merged);
    print_r($unique); // here is the issue
    // .....
}
```

and what happened here underneath the hood is :

`-` in the first iteration , print the array merged

`-` in the second iteration , print the second merge of the array which is holding a original array merged by another array

---

you have another issue in your code, array_merge needs two parameters, so you will need to create new array `$merged` to store your new data in it.

so , to print the final data , you need :

```
$merged = array();
for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
{ 
   $artist = explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist']); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,B,C` in second.

    $unique = array_unique(array_merge($merged, $artist));

}
print_r($unique);
```

i have fixed a quick demo , https://3v4l.org/HcvTD to check how it works

Comment: When I go outside the loop it prints only first row, not both.

Comment: Not working dude. Printing `Array ( [0] = A` not even first row's all artist.

Comment: Can you suggest me a good and suitable title for this post? If you understood the problem properly.

Comment: In your demo u declared `$FILE[0]` and `$FILE[1]` before lool. But in my code Both are not known before the loop.

Comment: i statically defined the array because you are fetching data from database, so i had to do this to make my example works, you will need to edit my example for sure

Comment: How to fetch multiple rows in results as array without loop.

Comment: simply leave the loop and , `print_r($FILE);`

Comment: Not got solution yet. +1 for this but in working demo code you wrote `$FILE[0]` and `$FILE[1]` and `for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)` this will merge array like this `array_merge($FILE[0], $FILE[1])` but `$FILE` may contain more MySQL rows. For example if SQL query returns with 4 rows then `array_merge` shoud `array_merge($FILE[0], $FILE[1], $FILE[2], $FILE[3])`. How to perform it. Apologies for bad English.